# Npm error. I not able to install any package. Its throwing a error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

Error:

```
error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-native-randombytes" "--save"
error node v4.4.7
error npm  v2.15.8
error code EPEERINVALID
error peerinvalid The package react-native@0.34.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
error peerinvalid Peer react-native-scrollable-tab-view@0.6.0 wants react-native@>=0.20.0
error peerinvalid Peer react-native-maps@0.11.0 wants react-native@>=0.35.
```

Comment: please post your package.json

Comment: "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.34.1",
    "react-native-button": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-hamburger": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-redux-router": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your react-native version needs to be >= .35 for the version of react-native-maps you are trying to use. Currently you have it set at 0.34.1 for react-native which doesn't satisfy react-native-maps. You could either upgrade react-native or try an earlier version of react-native-maps that works with the version of react-native you are using.